# How to install vtk for python in windows-10 via pip?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, vtk

I tried installing vtk via pip as "pip install vtk" but it returned an error as below.

ERROR:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk (from
>   versions: none)

ERROR:

> No matching distribution found for vtk"

How do I solve it?

Comment: What OS? What version of Python?

Comment: windows 10 -64bit and python 3.7.4

Comment: Check if Python is 32- or 64-bit: `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"`

Comment: python installed is 32bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`vtk` 8.1.2](https://pypi.org/project/vtk/8.1.2/#files) provides only 64-bit releases and no source code. Your Python is 32-bit. To install `vtk` you need to upgrade to 64-bit Python.